# Disable public holiday, and specific time range selected on calendar for every Saturday

Tags: javascript

I'm new in coding and trying to create an online booking appointment, but I couldn't figure out how to disable the selected public holiday on Calendar. Moreover, how to make the specific time range dependent on the calendar day?

e.g. On every Saturday, the time range only starts from 8:30 am to 12:00 pm. Another 5 days start from 8:30 am to 5:00 pm? Appreciate if you can help me.

My coding:

```
<div class="md-form mb-0">
   <label>Preferred Date</label>
     <input type=text id="PreferedDate" name="PreferedDate" class="form-control">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(function() { 
            $("#PreferedDate").datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
                minDate: 1,
                beforeShowDay: my_check 
            }); 
        }); 

        function my_check(in_date) { 
            if (in_date.getDay() == 0) { 
                return [false, "notav", 'Not Available']; 
            } else { 
                return [true, "av", "available"]; 
            } 
        } 
    }) 
</script>

<div class="md-form mb-0">
   <label>Preferred Time</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="PreferedTime" id="time">

        <script>
            //coding here?
        </script>

        <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
        <option value="8:15 AM">8:15 AM</option>
        <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
        <option value="8:45 AM">8:45 AM</option>

        <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
        <option value="9:15 AM">9:15 AM</option>
        <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
        <option value="9:45 AM">9:45 AM</option>

        <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
        <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
        <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
        <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>

        <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
        <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
        <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
        <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>

        <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
        <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
        <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
        <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>

        <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
        <option value="1:15 PM">1:15 PM</option>
        <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
        <option value="1:45 PM">1:45 PM</option>

        <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
        <option value="2:15 PM">2:15 PM</option>
        <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
        <option value="2:45 PM">2:45 PM</option>

        <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
        <option value="3:15 PM">3:15 PM</option>
        <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
        <option value="3:45 PM">3:45 PM</option>

        <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
        <option value="4:15 PM">4:15 PM</option>
        <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
        <option value="4:45 PM">4:45 PM</option>

        <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
        <option value="5:15 PM">5:15 PM</option>
        <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>            
      </select>                                 
   </div>
```

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: Re-post the coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So this code is for friday if you change the value of if as displayed in comments too you can fix it for your problem i hope it will help you !!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="abb">
        <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
        <option value="8:15 AM">8:15 AM</option>
        <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
        <option value="8:45 AM">8:45 AM</option>

        <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
        <option value="9:15 AM">9:15 AM</option>
        <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
        <option value="9:45 AM">9:45 AM</option>

        <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
        <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
        <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
        <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>

        <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
        <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
        <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
        <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>

        <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
        <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
        <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
        <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>

        <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
        <option value="1:15 PM">1:15 PM</option>
        <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
        <option value="1:45 PM">1:45 PM</option>

        <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
        <option value="2:15 PM">2:15 PM</option>
        <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
        <option value="2:45 PM">2:45 PM</option>

        <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
        <option value="3:15 PM">3:15 PM</option>
        <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
        <option value="3:45 PM">3:45 PM</option>

        <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
        <option value="4:15 PM">4:15 PM</option>
        <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
        <option value="4:45 PM">4:45 PM</option>

        <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
        <option value="5:15 PM">5:15 PM</option>
        <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
        </div>
    </select>
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDay();
        var abb = document.querySelector('#abb')
        console.log(n)
        if (n === 5) //5 is for friday, saturday =6 
{
            for (let index = 0; index < abb.children.length; index++) {
                if (abb[index].value <= '12:00 PM' || abb[index].value >= '8:00 AM')
                    abb[index].disabled = false
                else
                    abb[index].disabled = true
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've put the coding to my program, but it follows our laptop actual day. what if I want to follow the calendar Saturdays I selected on the booking appointment calendar? What can I do?

Comment: Dates in Javascript is considered as the 6th day as i have used if(n===5) instead of 5 use 6 so it will work for all the Saturdays :)